# ML/DS in fixed income asset management

Tags: fixed-income, data, machine-learning, asset-allocation

I am new to the topic but I would like to read papers/books/anything interesting to learn more how ML and data science is used in buy side Fixed income Asset management firms. Factor investing/signals/etc? I have no idea how it can be used but I would love to know more! I would be interested in actual projects with implementation details.